# Pyspark - Count non zero columns in a spark data frame for each row

Tags: pyspark

I have dataframe, I need to count number of non zero columns by row in Pyspark.

```
ID COL1 COL2 COL3
1  0    1    -1 
2  0    0     0 
3 -17   20    15
4  23   1     0
```

Expected Output:

```
ID COL1 COL2 COL3 Count
1   0    1    -1    2
2   0    0     0    0
3  -17   20    15   3
4   23   1     0    1
```

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: input and expected output mismatches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various approaches to achieve this, below I am listing one of the simple approaches -

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    [1,  0,    1,    -1], 
    [2,  0,    0,     0],
    [3, -17,   20,    15],
    [4,  23,   1,     0]], 
    ["ID", "COL1", "COL2", "COL3"]
)

#Check columns list removing ID columns
df.columns[1:]
['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3']

#import functions
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#Adding new column count having sum/addition(if column !=0 then 1 else 0)
df.withColumn(
    "count",
    sum([
            F.when(F.col(cl) != 0, 1).otherwise(0) for cl in df.columns[1:]
    ])
).show()


+---+----+----+----+-----+
| ID|COL1|COL2|COL3|count|
+---+----+----+----+-----+
|  1|   0|   1|  -1|    2|
|  2|   0|   0|   0|    0|
|  3| -17|  20|  15|    3|
|  4|  23|   1|   0|    2|
+---+----+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: I keep getting column not iterable when I used the above code.  
    But I changed the code to:  
    row_Sum_not_0 = (reduce(add,(when(column(x)!=0,1).otherwise(0) for x in df.columns[1:]))).alias("count")  
    df.select(row_Sum_not_0).show()

Comment: @VivekReddy This is also the same thing. and Above example is tested on spark v1.6, it is executing without and exception. Probably you are missing something

Comment: @jxc There is a difference between `sum` & `F.sum`. `F.sum` wouldn't work in this situation. As we need sum at row level instead column level. `F.sum` works when we need to `sum` column.

Comment: @VivekReddy How are you importing functions? If you are importing like `pyspark.sql import functions as F` then this is good. Else if you are importing like `from pyspark.sql.functions  import *` or `pyspark.sql.functions   import sum, col, when` then you will get exception you mentioned above.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but none of these suggestions work - I keep getting 'Column not iterable'
I've tried so many combinations, in particular:
`tmp2 = tmp2.select('*', expr(f"sum([when(col(cl) > 0, 1) for cl in {triglist}])") ) ` ; 
`.withColumn('num_unq_triggers', expr(count([when(col(cl) > 0, 1) for cl in triglist])) ) `; `.withColumn('num_unq_triggers', expr(sum([when(col(cl) > 0, 1).otherwise(0) for cl in triglist])) ) `
I've tried putting quotations marks inside the brackets for 'expr' function, that also doesnt work. Also tried all sorts of combinations of `f.when` or `f.sum`.